# error C2976: 'QMap' : too few template arguments in QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Tags: qt, signals-slots

i tryt to invoke QMetaObject::invokeMethod from object to the caller object
i have this from the object :

```
bool bReturnInvokeMethod = false;
bool bInvokeMethod1= QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_pCollector,
                            "setStack",
                            Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                            Q_ARG(QMap<QString,QVector<std::string > >, linksQTResultMap));
```

but im getting this error:

```
error C2976: 'QMap' : too few template arguments
```

why its well defined type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the C++ preprocessor isn't aware of templates, and `Q_ARG` is a macro.

When the preprocessor sees:

```
Q_MAP(foo<bar,baz>,blop)
```

It's interpreted as a three distinct arguments (quotes to make it more visible):

```
Q_MAP( "foo<bar" , "baz>" , "blop" )
```

and the resulting expansion doesn't make sense.

Something that usually works to counter this is to use a typedef:

```
typedef QMap<QString,QVector<std::string> > MyStringVectorMap;
...
Q_MAP(MyStringVectorMap, linksQTResultMap)
...
```